# can't increase gcache.size galera cluster mariadb

Tags: mariadb, galera

i wanted to increase the value of gcache.size on my 3 nodes of the mariadb galera cluster (galera v25.3.22(r3764), mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.33 - MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1), from the standard 128MB to 1G.

I have sufficient space on my disk.

I shutdown all 3 nodes, change the parameter in the my.cnf:

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=1G"
restart the nodes, but the size stays same (on disk as in the wsrep_provider_options).

is this a bug?

I can for example change these 2 parameters without problem:

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.recover=yes"

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.page_size=1G"
but the gcache.size doesnt increase

Comment: Don't you mean `size` instead of `page_size`?

Comment: yes, size, but if I leave out the other parameters (page_size and recover=yes), it works.
why is that gcache.recover=yes for then?  you can use it in combination with gcache.size?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your configuration file only has one instance of the wsrep_provider_options otherwise the last instance is used.

http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/galeraparameters.html

Settings for wsrep_provider_options should be defined as a semicolon-separated key value pair list, such as key1 = value1; key2 = value2.